# all items in a single async call

Tags: async-await, next.js, rss

Can someone help with this code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-keldysh-x058u6?file=/pages/feeds/%5Bslug%5D.js)?

I wanna show all the feeds from the 3 sites (stored in FEEDS) in a homepage without have to click and go to slug page.

the problem is how to use nextjs to do multiple async call.

Im a newbie so every help will be appreciated!

thanks guys

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) & `Promise.all`. I have updated your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-pare-15lnl5), you can see the first feed xml (nextjs one) in `console.log`, just fyi netlify one is 404.

```
function Home({ feeds }) {
  console.log(feeds[0]);
...
}

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  let feeds = [];
  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(FEEDS.map((feed) => fetch(feed.url)));
    feeds = await Promise.all(data.map((res) => res.text()));
    for (let item of feeds) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return { feeds };
};
```

Comment: Ty man, but i've understood how to solve only 50% of the problem ahaha.
I dont understand how to pass the new list in the parser.
When i have to call getFeed method?

Ty again

Comment: @sedprc what are you trying to display/do exactly?

Comment: what I would like to see is a homepage that already shows all the feeds from the different sources without having to click on the individual source.
In other words, I want an homepage with a unique feed list.
UI Example:
`----------------  
Homepage  

Nextjs Blog. 
feed 1. 
feed 2. 
feed 3. 
...  
Vercel Blog. 
feed 1. 
feed 2. 
feed 3. 
..  
other source. 
feed 1. 
feed 2. 
feed 3. 
...  
----------------`.